# generate random number (non-repeating integer) in oracle based on the count in oracle

Tags: oracle, random

Seeing if I can generate a non-repeater random integer based on the total count-
For example with code below-

```
with all_val as (    
select 1 as ID, 'A' as val from dual  union all 
select 2 as ID, 'A' as val from dual  union all 
select 3 as ID, 'A' as val from dual  union all  
select 4 as ID, 'B' as val from dual  union all 
select 5 as ID, 'B' as val from dual  union all  
select 6 as ID, 'B' as val from dual  union all 
select 7 as ID, 'A' as val from dual  union all 
select 8 as ID, 'A' as val from dual  union all 
select 9 as ID, 'A' as val from dual)

select A.*,
(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE( 0, X?? )) as RND from (
select B.* from all_val B
where VAL <> 'B') A;
```

ID's 1-3 & 7-9 would be selected but the random number generated could only be 1-6.

Hope this makes sense.

TIA

Comment: Please clarify the rules. Why do you expect it to be in range 1-6, but not 1-9 or 9-1000000?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the random number to range from 1 to the number of rows the query returns, you can get this by passing `count(*) over ()` as the upper limit for `dbms_random.value`:

```
with all_val as (    
  select 1 as ID, 'A' as val from dual  union all 
  select 2 as ID, 'A' as val from dual  union all 
  select 3 as ID, 'A' as val from dual  union all  
  select 4 as ID, 'B' as val from dual  union all 
  select 5 as ID, 'B' as val from dual  union all  
  select 6 as ID, 'B' as val from dual  union all 
  select 7 as ID, 'A' as val from dual  union all 
  select 8 as ID, 'A' as val from dual  union all 
  select 9 as ID, 'A' as val from dual
)

select
  a.*,
  round ( dbms_random.value ( 1, count (*) over () ) ) as rnd
from(
  select b.*
  from   all_val b
  where  val <> 'B'
) a;

ID    VAL    RND    
    1 A           1 
    2 A           2 
    3 A           6 
    7 A           5 
    8 A           6 
    9 A           3
```

Comment: Problem is that it is still repeating of the random numbers, the RND should be 1-6 with no repeating integers. May be sufficient for what I need though. Thank you.

Comment: @LawrenceBlock - what exactly do you mean by "no repeating integers"?

Comment: As in, the RND should have 1-6 but none of the numbers can be repeated. Hope that helps

Comment: @LawrenceBlock - you want to assign the numbers 1-6 to the rows in a random order?

Comment: Have you tried "select row_number() over(order by dbms_random.value()) as rn, d.* from all_val d where  val <> 'B'" ?

Comment: @ChrisSaxon- Yes.  Sorry for the delay in response.